# How convert a callback inside retrofit callback response from java to Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, callback

I am a newcomer to Kotlin and I have a simple question :
I convert all my project from java to kotlin and I succeed to correct all bugs with the documentation.

But I did not succeed to convert a call back inside java retrofit callback response to kotlin.

```
fun getUserAccountController(token: String, callback: UtilsCallback): Users {

        userAccountServices.getUserAccount(token).enqueue(object : Callback<Result> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Result>, response: Response<Result>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.i("Callback TOKEN ok ==> ", response.body()!!.resultUser!!.name)
                    user.name = response.body()!!.resultUser!!.name
                    user.username = response.body()!!.resultUser!!.username

                    callback.onData(user) // ==> Here my CALLBACK function
                } else {
                    user.username = ""
                    user.name = ""
                    callback.onData(user) // ==> Here my CALLBACK function
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Result>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.i("Callback TOKEN Nok ==> ", "error")
            }
        })
        return user
    }
```

My callback is the function callback.onData

```
   Handler().postDelayed({
        user = userAccountController.getUserAccountController(token) {
            fullName!!.text = user.name
            firstName!!.text = user.name
            email!!.text = user.username
        }
    }, 50)
}
```

And it converts my code by this above I do not understand why.

Here is below the message of the error :

[image: Kotlin code showing 'type mismatch' error]

Maybe, I have to do use another way? My purpose in that exemple is to get my data from the succeed asynchrone response in the order to update my activity.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT

I post also my previous JAVA code which worked well

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            user = userAccountController.getUserAccountController(token, new UtilsCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onData(Users userBack) {
                            fullName.setText(user.getName());
                            firstName.setText(user.getName());
                            email.setText(user.getUsername());
                        }
                    });
        }
    },50);
}
```

EDIT 2 My new kotlin code suggested by @Roland

```
    Handler().postDelayed({
        user = userAccountController.getUserAccountController(token, UtilsCallback {
            fullName!!.text = user.name
            firstName!!.text = user.name
            email!!.text = user.username
        })
    }, 50)
}
```

[image: Kotlin code showing 'interface does not have constructors' error]

EDIT 3 : My kotlin interface

```
    package com.util.my3ciapplication

import com.model.my3ciapplication.Users

interface UtilsCallback {

    fun onData(user: Users)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question should include all relevant details, please post your error as text (not as image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Roland for you help !

Here is the final correct response for helping.

```
val obj = object : UtilsCallback{
        override fun onData(user: Users) {
            fullName!!.text = user.name
            firstName!!.text = user.name
            email!!.text = user.username
        }
    }

    Handler().postDelayed({
        user = userAccountController.getUserAccountController(token, obj)
    }, 50)
}
```

Comment: while you can do that, I would rather suggest you to use the Kotlin functional style (e.g. `(Users) -> Unit`) instead... even more so, if that interface is just a Kotlin interface you got while transforming your Java code ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it says it there in the picture... you use `() -> Unit` and you should use `UtilsCallback` instead...

Probably the following will already work:

```
Handler().postDelayed({
  user = userAccountController.getUserAccountController(token, UtilsCallback {
        fullName!!.text = user.name
        firstName!!.text = user.name
        email!!.text = user.username
    })
  }, 50)
```

Or at least the solution will probably be very similar to this.

Update: I was assuming that was a Java interface... For your second error, please have also a look at [Kotlin: Interface ... does not have constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737785/kotlin-interface-does-not-have-constructors).

In that specific case I would rather replace your `UtilsCallback` with a similarly appropriate functional counterpart, e.g. `() -> Unit`

Comment: I tried but it doest not work :s thanks for answering

Comment: what was the problem when you did?

Comment: UtilsCallBack is an inteface so it told me that n interface cannot have constructors.

Comment: `UtilsCallback {` <-- this is not a constructor call... you are sure you used it the same way?

Comment: I post my previsous JAVA code on EDIT in my main post.

Comment: look at my code, carefully... it should work... I just saw that there was a bracket too much, but the main part stays the same...  `UtilsCallback {`, not `UtilsCallback() {`... and you need to put it in the `getUserAccountController(`-brackets... if it still doesn't work, please show your code then...

Comment: Hello thanks for you help first of all. I post the code you suggest me with the following screen error.

Comment: ah... this is a Kotlin interface? please have a look at: [Kotlin interface ... does not have constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737785/kotlin-interface-does-not-have-constructors)... you could basically exchange that `UtilsCallback` with a nice `() -> Unit` if you want... (or what is the most appropriate for you)... that way you can then even omit `UtilsCallback` and place it outside your brackets, as before...