# Why I receive Interface ... does not have constructors (I have Kotlin and java classes)?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger

Here is my Kotlin code  and when I build I receive Interface ImageSizeProvider does not have constructors

```
interface ImageSizeProvider {
    val spec: ImageSizeSpec
}

@FragmentScope
class ImageSizeProviderImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val mResources: Resources
) : ImageSizeProvider {
     override val spec: ImageSizeSpec
        get() = ...
}
and here is my java dagger interface ( I don't want to migrate this to Kotlin yet)




    @Module
public interface XXXModule {
    @Binds
    @FragmentScope
    ImageSizeProvider bindImageSizeProvider(ImageSizeProviderImpl imageSizeProvider);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Interfaces never have constructors because they are not classes.

Comment: I know but I receive that build error

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message you get with some context? (Line where it happens etc). The code you posted here seems fine so the issue is likely somewhere else.

Comment: I receive Interface ImageSizeProvider does not have constructors and it shows the line number  that doesn't exist in dagger module and it shows in dagger module that includes another module which actually does the provides.

Comment: @I.S Can you paste that error message with some context?

Comment: That error should be preceded by a file name and position.  Please check your code at the indicated position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [language documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html), a property declared in an `Interface` is abstract. Your declaration:

```
val spec ImageSizeSpec
```

is therefore abstract and you must provide an overridden declaration in any class that implements the `Interface`. Your `ImageSizeProviderImpl` doesn't contain an overridden declaration of `spec`.

If you create an instance of `ImageSizeProvider`, this will fail because the variable `spec` is not initialized.

Comment: I have ` override val spec: ImageSizeSpec` in the implementation.  I just didn't copy that code

Comment: You must set a value in your override. You aren't allowed to have modifiable data in an `Interface`, only constants.

Comment: original code in java for interface looks like
 ImageSizeSpec getSpec(); so it's only should be getter

Comment: Understand. Am trying to follow all of this. Do you try to instantiate `ImageSizeSpec` anywhere? It appears that this may be the source of the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43737785/kotlin-interface-does-not-have-constructors

Comment: Sorry, I meant "do you create an instance of `ImageSizeProvider`"?

Comment: Yes I have and I haven't noticed that I am initialising it somewhere.  I thought  I only inject it .thank you

Comment: I updated the answer. Do you want me to put anything else in the answer? I hope you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: No. problem, It is fixed, I haven't seen that it was initialised ,I thought I am only providing, you helped me to double check and see where I have it :)